# QT, QComboBox Item changed, when I repeatedly click on the second level sub item, the text data of the first level item will be displayed

Tags: qt, qt5

I am currently using QT's QComboBox and have implemented a multi-level menu based ComboBox based on TreeView. However, when I repeatedly click on the second level sub item, the text data of the first level item will be displayed. I think this may be because QCombox sets the first data item in the drop-down window to the selected state by default when updating data in the drop-down window, which will generate a signal of currentTextChanged, I have directly modified the original data in the logical layer.

Currently, I do not have any good solutions. I have tried the methods of disConnect and blockSignal, but they have not worked.

```
void RightControlPanel::assigCombox(QComboBox *combox){
// Create a custom combo box
QComboBox *customComboBox = new QComboBox;
QWidget *container = new QWidget;
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(container);

QStringList str = {"int", "float", "bool", "string"};
combox->addItems(str);

// Create a pop-up tree menu
QTreeWidget *treeWidget = new QTreeWidget;
treeWidget->setHeaderHidden(true);
QTreeWidgetItem *intItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
intItem->setText(0, "int");
QTreeWidgetItem *floatItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
floatItem->setText(0, "float");
QTreeWidgetItem *boolItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
boolItem->setText(0, "bool");
QTreeWidgetItem *stringItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
stringItem->setText(0, "string");

QString structPath = QDir::currentPath() + "/struct_Json/";
QStringList structItems = listFolderContents(structPath);
QTreeWidgetItem *structItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
structItem->setText(0, "Struct");
for (const QString &item : structItems)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem *childItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(structItem);
    childItem->setText(0, "struct/"+item);
}

QString enumPath = QDir::currentPath() + "/enum_json/";
QStringList enumItems = listFolderContents(enumPath);
QTreeWidgetItem *enumItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
enumItem->setText(0, "Enum");
for (const QString &item : enumItems)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem *childItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(enumItem);
    childItem->setText(0, "enum/"+item);
}

layout->addWidget(customComboBox);
layout->addWidget(treeWidget);

// Set custom combo boxes as dropdown menus
customComboBox->setEditable(true);
customComboBox->lineEdit()->setReadOnly(true);

customComboBox->setModel(treeWidget->model());
customComboBox->setView(treeWidget);
customComboBox->setMinimumWidth(200); 

// Set the custom combo box as a dropdown widget for QComboBox
combox->setModel(customComboBox->model());
combox->setView(customComboBox->view());
combox->setLineEdit(customComboBox->lineEdit());

combox->setEditable(true);
combox->lineEdit()->setReadOnly(true);  
}

connect(arrayCombox, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, this, &RightControlPanel::arrayComboxChange);

void RightControlPanel::arrayComboxChange(QString text)
{
    while (flayout5->rowCount())
   {
        flayout5->removeRow(flayout5->rowCount()-1);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry but we cannot answer without properly understand the context of the problem. Please provide a valid [mre].